# Why isn't Kiyor reading in Tehillas HaShem? Is it even necessary to recite Kiyor/Terumas hadeshen before Parshas tamid?

Tags: prayer-book, chabad, korbanos-ketores-prayers

OK, so in the Tehillas HaShem siddur in the Korbanos section of Shacharis, there is only Terumas hadeshen before Parshas Tamid. Why is Kiyor not in the korbanos before Terumas hadeshen in that siddur? Is it because we fulfill Kiyor with netilas yadayim? I have tried scouting the internet and seforim and asking Rovs for an answer but haven't found the answer for "Why?" to this question. Are Kiyor and Terumas hadeshen even required to recite before parshas hatamid?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya FrumYid and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 1):

Dayan Raskin suggests (in his annotated edition of the Baal Hatanya's siddur, [note 22](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=30450#p=128&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=)) that since we're not actually Kohanim serving in the Beis Hamikdash, we don't need to say the section about the Kiyor (in the same vein as that we don't need to stand when reciting Korbanos, as per the opinion of Tevuos Shor).

Comment: Wouldn't that apply too to the Terumas hadeshen and Tamid parsha then, since the whole service was performed by Kohanim serving in the beis hamikdash, since they would also offer the Tamid Korban?

Comment: One of the statements i read long ago on an article about korbanos i forgot which site it was was now, but the author wrote nowdays everybody can be a kohen in reciting Korbanos in the absence of beis hamikdash. It seemed very wrong to me as not every yid is a descendant of a kohen and that is their personal duty, and thus seeing yourself as a kohen when your not and reciting certain parts as if offering korbanos felt like intruding and stepping in on their duties.

Comment: @FrumYid The Tamid is probably different since it's brought on behalf of the entire Jewish people, so it would go under the category of "whoever studies the Torah of the olah-offering is as though he brought an olah." Terumas hadeshen - not sure, though in the Siddur Im Dach there's an explanation of the spiritual significance of that as a preparation for davening, so maybe that's why we say it. || Every Jew can be a Kohen in a certain limited sense (hence can be saying the Korbanos); see Rambam, end of Hilchos Shemittah V'Yovel.